# Firefox does not show the error message of forms after multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox, browser

Firefox stops displaying the default constraint-violation message of the form if the user clicks multiple time (seems 3) on the input elements or on the submit button.
For example the following input field is marked as required: if I leave it empty and click the submit button once, firefox correctly displays the error message. If I click the button or the input field two more times, firefox stops showing the message and starts just focusing on the field that makes the validity check fail. As an additional problem, the browser will no longer show the error message until the page is reloaded. I tried Firefox 91.0.2 and 92.0 (just downloaded, latest version).

The behaviour I want is the one of Chrome, IE and Safari: if i click the button and the validity check fails, then the error message is shown no matters how many time i click. Is there any way to force this behaviour in FF?

Ps: the submit button is actually of type button, not submit. I need it to be a button but I tried also with type=submit and the behaviour did not change.

```js
    function mySubmit(formId){
        let form = document.getElementById(formId);
        if(form.reportValidity()) {
            window.alert("submit");
            form.reset();
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" required name="name" autocomplete="off">
    <button onclick="mySubmit('myForm')" type="button" class="submitButton" lang="en">Submit</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code seams kind of complicated. If you have to perform some JS code on submit of the form I will suggest an event listener like this:

```js
document.forms.myForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  alert('submit');
  e.target.reset();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" required name="name" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="submitButton" lang="en">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need to stop the submit action and/or listen for the invalid event on the input element (and display your own message to the user).

```js
document.forms.myForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('submit');
  e.target.reset();
});

document.forms.myForm.name.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('invalid');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" required name="name" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="submitButton" lang="en">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```